# Javascript ECMASCRIPT w/ Graphql

Tags: javascript, compatibility, graphql

Looking to implement graphql in an existing non-ecmascript6 stack without babel. I'm not sure if graphql's javascript interfaces support that. I can't find any documentation stating either way.

Does anyone know if graphql is compatible to be used with javascript ecmascript5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `graphql-js` library bundles before publishing to npm, so you're not required to use `babel` in your consuming app unless you so choose.

Comment: What does bundling mean?

Comment: Poor terminology on my part. They run their code through babel before publishing to `npm`. You can easily use their library without worrying about implementing babel in your stack (I do this myself)